# Make div take up 100% of page unless another div is present

Tags: html, resize, width

I'm trying to format a checkout page.  The page shows an order summary on the left and recommended products on the right.  When no recommended products are being used I'd like the order summary to stretch 100% of the page.

Currently the order summary is setup with a `float:left; width:720px;`.  While the recommended products `float:right;width:240;`.

If I take the width out of the order summary or change it to 100% or auto it simply goes below the recommended products.

I tried attaching a photo that explains everything but I guess StackOverFlow restricts new users from posting photos.

Comment: If you add the link to the photo another user can edit it in.

Comment: Do you have access to jQuery?

Comment: Is this fiddle an accurate depiction of the layout you're dealing with?

Comment: @user A comment from your side would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is all you need: [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/IkOwUwU/2/edit)

[image]

```
<div class="summary">
  <div>Order summary...</div>
  <div>Products...</div>
</div>
```

```
.summary{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
.summary>div{
  display:table-cell;
}
.summary>div:first-child{
  background:gray;
}
.summary>div:nth-child(2){
  background:orange;
  width:240px;
}
```

Comment: Clicked in expecting to tell him to use Javascript but, while reliant on implementation, your answer taught me something.  Very cool!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this describe your situation. Try toggling back and forth with the button on the bottom:

http://jsfiddle.net/T2Quv/21/

The key here is setting the width dynamically from javascript based on whether the recommended products are show or hidden:

```
$('.mrbutton').click(function(){
   $('.rec').toggle(); 

    if($('.rec').css('display') == 'none'){
    $('.checkout').css('width', '100%');  
    }else{
       $('.checkout').css('width', '69%');  
        };
 });
```

You haven't told us how recommended products is shown/hidden, but hopefully this helps.